# How to implement this animation?

Tags: jquery, templates, animation, knockout.js

I want to implement this simple animation in knockout:

```
function scroll(back) {
    var scrollContainer = $('.scrollingContent');
    var newContent = $("<div class='content'></div>");
    var oldContent = scrollContainer.children().first();
    newContent.css("width", "50%");
    var contentSize = oldContent.width();
    var newContentColor = oldContent.css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" ? 
                                                                "green" : "red";
    newContent.css("backgroundColor", newContentColor);
    if (back) {
        newContent.css("margin-left", -contentSize);
        scrollContainer.prepend(newContent);
        newContent.animate({ "margin-left": 0 }, 600, 
        function () { oldContent.remove(); });
    } else {
        scrollContainer.append(newContent);
        oldContent.animate({ "margin-left": -contentSize }, 600, 
        function () { oldContent.remove(); });
    }
}
```

Example can be looked at here: http://jsfiddle.net/VMx3j/106/

I've read a lot about custom bindings, but I still can't understand how to do it right.

I had just two ideas. First was to create an foreach array and to bind on afterRender, afterAdd, or beforeRemove. But will it be correct? I think the code in this case won't be enough understandable and it will be very hard to change anything. Also another idea was to create a custom binding. But as far as I understood this approach works only with one element, and I need access to at least two of them.

Also notice that content element is template (that is constantly changed by this animation).

Please help if you have any ideas about it.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I can't because previous questions haven't been answered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer:

```
this.afterElementAdd = function(element) {
    if (element.nodeType === 1) {
        var el = $(element);
        if (el.next().length != 0 && el.prev().length == 0) {
            el.animate({ "margin-left": "0" }, 300, function () {
                self.contents.pop();
            });
        }
        else if (el.prev().length != 0 && el.next().length == 0) {
            el.prev().animate({ "margin-left": -el.width() }, 300, function () {
                self.contents.shift();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you are willing to do. It will be a picture carousel, right? :)

Yes, make an array for the elements!

```
<script>
var $pics = $('#pics img'); // Get all img elements (this is an array/object !)
var i = 0;                  // Index starts with zero
var len = $pics.length;     // How many pictures we have

var $curr = $pics.eq(i);                       // Access current element
var $next = $pics.eq( i+1 == len ? 0 : i+1 );  // Access next element
var $prev = $pics.eq( i == 0 ? len-1 : i-1 );  // Access previous element
</script>
```

I believe that now you will know what to do. :)